# Need help understanding adding cron job to plesk

Tags: php, cron, plesk, cron-task, plesk-onyx

I've installed a new script and they've asked me to add this cron job to my plesk and they doesn't support plesk :/

anyway here is the code line

```
*/5 * * * * php /var/www/httpdocs/process_file_queue.cron.php >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I understand that it's php and the path is "/var/www/httpdocs/process_file_queue.cron.php" but what time exactly is "*/5 * * * *" and i'm not sure is the "/dev/null 2>&1" arguments??

Comment: surely you can Google that

Comment: @Hossam Ahmed You can set up scheduled tasks with plesk. Have a look at this https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/server-administration/scheduling-tasks.64993/